# PhotoKit is not available?

Tags: photokit

[image]

This problem is so weird, the API is available for iOS 8.0+, why the XCode is giving this error? Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it has been renamed to Photos

So if you just use `import Photos` it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If `Photos` doesn't work, try `import PhotosUI` instead.  That worked for me.